# Defining a static class member inside of another namespace

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

If I have a class with private static members in a namespace:

```
namespace A {
class T {
    public: 
        //functions
    private:
        static bool a;
        static unsigned int b;
```

And I am doing unit testing of this class in another file such as:

```
namespace {

bool A::T::a = false;
unsigned int A::T::b = 1;

/* tests declaring an instance of A...*/
```

I receive the error from Clang:

`error: cannot define or redeclare 'a' here because namespace '' does not enclose namespace 'T'`
`error: cannot define or redeclare 'b' here because namespace '' does not enclose namespace 'T'`

I have looked at other answers regarding static private members and the need to declare them where the declaration of the class is, which is what I believe I am doing here, but the error still escapes me.

Comment: `namespace {` is anonymous. Definition as the declaration was proposed in `namespace A`, it can't be done there, period.

Answer (score 1):

> I have looked at other answers regarding static private members and the need to declare them where the declaration of the class is, which is what I believe I am doing here,

No, you are not doing that. If the declaration is in "foo.h", the definition should be in "foo.cpp", not in a file used for unit testing.

> but the error still escapes me.

```
namespace {
```

defines an anonymous `namespace`, which is different from the global scope. Names declared in the anonymous `namespace` are visible only in the translation unit. Anything defined in the anonymous `namespace` must be declared in that `namespace` also.

You can use:

```
bool A::T::a = false;
unsigned int A::T::b = 1;
```

Better still, use:

```
namespace A {

    bool T::a = false;
    unsigned int T::b = 1;
```

and put those lines of code in the .cpp file corresponding to the .h file, not in the unit test file.